# Missing argument option in sfdisk?

Tags: ubuntu, compatibility, sfdisk

```
sfdisk --delete $disk
```

From Ubuntu 18.04 or later works. What is the equivalent command in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS?

[Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (--delete missing)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/sfdisk.8.html),

[Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (--delete present)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/sfdisk.8.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution 1:** build and install sfdisk from sources (to be able to use a more recent version)

```
wget https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/util-linux/v2.35/util-linux-2.35.tar.gz
tar -xvf util-linux-2.35.tar.gz
cd cd util-linux-2.35
./configure 
make
make install
/usr/local/bin/sfdisk --delete $disk
```

**Solution 2:** use [`fdisk`](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-how-to-delete-a-partition-with-fdisk-command/)

```
# list disk and partitions
fdisk -l
# open the target disk with fdisk
fdisk /dev/target-disk
# then use the d command option to delete the partition you want to remove
# then use the w command option to save the changes
```

Answer (score 0):

`wipefs -a -f $disk`

will [do the trick](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man8/wipefs.8.html)